# How can I replace HttpContext.Current.Session moving from WCF to Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

WCF allows me to set session values for the duration of an `[OperationContract]` method call.

Migrating to Web API this will no longer work. Is there something else I can use without changing method signatures for `ApiController` calls?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you putting into session?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen a string value that determines database the application retrieves data from.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store values for the remainder of the request you could put it in `HttpRequestMessage.Properties`. Here is an example with a `DelegatingHandler` that gets called before the controller:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Properties.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var someValue = Request.Properties["SomeKey"];

        // do stuff

        return Ok();
    }
}
```